# Microsoft Graph "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again" in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

This is my code to get emails from my email account through Microsoft Graph, but I keep getting an error regardless on credentials.

Code:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "";
var clientId = "";
var clientSecret = "";

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var inboxMessages = await graphClient
                        .Users["email"]
                        .MailFolders["inbox"]
                        .Messages
                        .Request()
                        .Expand("attachments")
                        .Top(20)
                        .GetAsync();
Console.WriteLine(inboxMessages);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Error:

[image]

Permissions:

[image]

Comment: In the client credential flow there won't be any user authentication, so delegated permissions doesn't work. Please give application permissions in the API permissions in azure as to make it work.

Comment: Let me know if this worked for you. Will convert it to answer.

Comment: But the permissions aren't the ones of the printscreen above? @ShivaKeshavVarma Thank you for your reply

Comment: No, there are two types of permissions. Application permissions and delegated permissions. Here if you have a user logging into the app then you would use a different flow and you can use these delegated permissions. But here there is no user as it's a client credential flow. So use application permissions to make the above code work.

Comment: Got it.  Check the post with the updated printscreen of my permissions. Is that what I need to do? If it is, it still doesn't work @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma Actually it worked. Thank you so much! Put it as an awnser !!!! THANKS!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you!! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the client credential flow there won't be any user authentication, so delegated permissions doesn't work. Please give application permissions in the API permissions in azure ad.

There are two types of permissions. Application permissions and delegated permissions. Here if you have a user logging into the app then you would use a different flow and you can use these delegated permissions. But here there is no user as it's a client credential flow. So use application permissions to make the above code work.